# Gradle reusable custom task for each project modules

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

How to define a custom task that is reusable for modules? In my case, I'd like to use an `Exec` task to run a script with `commandLine` arguments specific to subprojects.

For example:

**script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "$@"
```

**build.gradle**

```
task customExecTask(type: Exec) {
  if (project.name == "a") {
    commandLine './script', "Project 'a'"
  } else if (project.name == "b") {
    commandLine './script', "Project 'b'"
  }
}

project('a') {
  build.dependsOn ':customExecTask'
}

project('b') {
  build.dependsOn ':customExecTask'
}
```

#### EDIT

Or something like this:

```
task customExecTask(type: Exec) {
  def dynamicVariable = ""
  commandLine './script', dynamicVariable
}

project('a') {
  task(':customExecTask').dynamicVariable = "Project 'a'"
  build.dependsOn ':customExecTask'
}

project('b') {
  task(':customExecTask').dynamicVariable = "Project 'b'"
  build.dependsOn ':customExecTask'
}
```

Expected result:

```
$ gradle :a:build
Project 'a'

$ gradle :b:build
Project 'b'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the documentation on [Using Gradle Plugins](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html).

As per this [topic](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:script_plugins), you could place the task in a separate gradle file `mytask.gradle` and in each module you add to build.gradle:

`apply from: "${rootDir}/pathtomycustomgradlefile/mytask.gradle"`

If you need more logic to decide which one to apply, you could check the topic [Applying plugins to subprojects](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:subprojects_plugins_dsl).

Comment: It's just a simple Exec task that would execute a script with optional arguments depending on the subproject. Please see my edited question again for an additional logic to what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this answer. I have a solution now without creating a separate `.gradle` file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. As for my first example, I simply wanted to execute a script that is in the root project directory with specific arguments for each sub-project. For the task to work properly, you'll have to define the task in the `subprojects` closure. The following is a fully working example for a single `build.gradle` setup.

Directory structure:

```
├─ a                 # Module 'a' folder
├─ b                 # Module 'b' folder
├─ build.gradle      # Root project build file
├─ script            # Executable bash script
└─ **/               # Other files and folder
```

**script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
echo "$@"
```

**build.gradle**

```
subprojects { // Define the task here
  task customExecTask(type: Exec) {
    // Change the directory where the script resides
    workingDir = rootDir
    // Conditional arguments depending on each project modules.
    // We'll use the property 'project.name' to determine the
    // current project this task is running from
    def customArgs = project.name == 'a' ? "Hello" : "World"
    // Then execute the script with customArgs variable
    commandLine './script', customArgs
    // Or in Windows: commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'script.bat'
  }
}

project('a') {
  build.dependsOn 'customExecTask'
}

project('b') {
  build.dependsOn 'customExecTask'
}
```

Console result:

```
$ gradle build

> Task :a:execute
Hello

> Task :b:execute
World
```